# app crash when i get nil data from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

my code when i fetch data from database:-

```
while(sqlite3_step(dataRows) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            clsGlobal *temp=[[clsGlobal alloc]init];
            //temp.CatId=sqlite3_column_int(dataRows,0);
            temp.QId =sqlite3_column_int(dataRows,0);
            temp.QName= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(dataRows,1)];
            temp.ImagePath= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(dataRows,2)]; //app crash when imagepath is nil

            NSLog(@"%d%@%@",temp.QId,temp.QName,temp.ImagePath);
```

So please give me right suggestion and helpful links .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the pointer before trying to turn it into an `NSString`:

```
char *text = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(dataRows,2);
temp.ImagePath = text ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:text] : @"no image path in database";
```